# Only one instance of a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have some runnable code that is executed through a thread.The thread is executed by multiple pieces of code how can I make sure there is only one thread that executes that runnable at a certain point.

I tried using a boolean value that is true on thread start and becomes false at thread end but that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Luksprog no... i have put it as a global variable in the main class

Comment: You need to clarify the question.

Comment: @auselen I think is pretty clear more than 3 people understood it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class MyThread extends Thread
{
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void run()
    {
        if (MyThread.lock.tryLock())
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO something
            }
            finally
            {
                MyThread.lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use ReentrantLock instead of "synchronized" block here.

Comment: @Andrew . Sorry I'm not very familiar with `ReentrantLock` .. Please feel free to edit the answer...

Comment: @Madushan if i declare lock static than the class must be declared static too

Answer (score 3):

**-** First of all **its the resources of an object that multiple threads access.**

**-** Now if you want to let only 1 thread access that resource at an instance of time, then you can do the followings**:**

**1.** Use `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` with number of thread equals 1, so only 1 thread at an time instance can access that resource.

**Eg:**

`Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);`

**2.** You can also use `SingleThreadExecutor`, as it completes one task before going on the the second on and and so on. So there is **No need of using synchronization.**

Comment: I think the semaphore is better option than extending the thread. Would assume the run mehtod would do a check before allowing to execute the business logic.